# check if a specific section is on a screen to add a class to a specific navigation item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation menu that consists of dots each of which points to a specific div with an id. What I need is to make a dot bigger when a specific div is on a screen. Let's say, if I scroll down to the 'where' section, I want the dot that points to this section get a class 'active', so I can make some visual effect with css.

```
<nav class="header__nav">
    <ul class="header__list">
        <li class="header__list-item">
            <a href="#intro"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__list-item">
            <a href="#about"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__list-item">
            <a href="#range"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__list-item">
            <a href="#why-us"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__list-item">
            <a href="#where"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__list-item">
            <a href="#footer"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 1000, 'swing');
    });
});
```

Comment: so do you getting some error  ?

Comment: I just have no code. I don't know how to track if the section is on a screen

Comment: In “I don’t know” cases you are supposed to first of all do some _research_ on your own! What has that brought up so far? “track if html element is currently in view” or similar typed into Google should give you plenty to work with already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script will be execute on scroll and check add the class name 'active' to specified navigation menu which is visible on screen.

```
 var $sections = $('.box');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var $currentSection
        $sections.each(function () {
            var divPosition = $(this).offset().top;
            if (divPosition - 100 < currentScroll) {
                $currentSection = $(this);
            }
            if ($currentSection) {
                var id = $currentSection.attr('id');
                $('a').removeClass('active');
                $("[href='#" + id + "']").addClass('active');
            }
        })

    });
```

integrated code.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash;
            var $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
            }, 1000, 'swing');
        });

        var $sections = $('.box');
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
            var $currentSection
            $sections.each(function () {
                var divPosition = $(this).offset().top;
                if (divPosition - 100 < currentScroll) {
                    $currentSection = $(this);
                }
                if ($currentSection) {
                    var id = $currentSection.attr('id');
                    $('a').removeClass('active');
                    $("[href='#" + id + "']").addClass('active');
                }
            })

        });
    });
```

```css
    ul {
        position: fixed;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: #666;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            li a:hover:not(.active) {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }

            li a.active {
                color: white;
                background-color: #4CAF50;
            }

    .box {
        padding-top: 80px;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <nav class="header__nav">
        <ul class="header__list">
            <li class="header__list-item">
                <a href="#intro">intro</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__list-item">
                <a href="#about">about</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__list-item">
                <a href="#range">range</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__list-item">
                <a href="#why-us">why-us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__list-item">
                <a href="#where">where</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__list-item">
                <a href="#footer">footer</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
        <div id="intro" class="box">Introduction</div>
        <div id="about" class="box">About us</div>
        <div id="range" class="box">Range</div>
        <div id="why-us" class="box">why us</div>
        <div id="where" class="box">where</div>
        <div id="footer" class="box">footer</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to extend your jQuery. So you can easy check if an element is in viewport:

```
$.fn.elementIsInViewport = function() {

    var
    elementTop = $(this).offset().top,
    elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight(),
    viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;

};
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {

    if ($('#where').elementisInViewport()) {

        // do something

    } else {

        // do something else

    } });
```